# Using Mac Terminal To Run .EXE

Tags: macos, exe

One of my friends sent me a link on how to use terminal to get OSU! to run on mac. It worked perfectly, but now I am wondering if it is only for certain things, or if I can use terminal commands to make a .exe program run?
Anyone know if this is possible, and if so how would I go about doing it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Macs aren’t compatible with Windows apps.
But you can try an app called wine.
Wine tries to provide an environment to run Windows exes.
Download the binary packages at [here](https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/macosx/download.html)

Get the stable installer.
Make sure that you’ve got xquartz installed using homebrew: brew install xquartz.

Comment: I have tried using wine before to run programs but have had very little luck, only managing to get 2 out of at least 10 to run. I have also tried to do this before, for this app, using wine but was not successful. I mainly just wanted to ask about using terminal to see if anything like that was possible.

Comment: Then you can try some virtualisation software, such as VirtualBox

Comment: Or these softwares: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/running-windows-app-on-other-platforms/

Comment: I have used VirtualBox and other similar programs, but have not had good experiences with them. They take a while to turn on and run extremely slow and just aren't practical for me.

Comment: You can try VMWare Fusion. You can either get a free license, or get a 30-day free trial

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and free way to run .exe files is to run it on ["PlayOnMac"](https://www.playonmac.com/en/). It might show some bugs(never faced a major bug). but it solves the problem. You can easily copy paste files on it like if you want to crack the software.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).